# SQL Server 2012 - How to access installation media to add features to an existing installation

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited a SQL Server 2012 Developer edition database. I want to add replication. Is there any way to find out where on the file system the required installation media is (for 2017 it's in C:SQLSever2017media). Or is there any where I can get the installation media? I have searched but can't find (free) Developer edition installation media older than 2014?

One solution is to migrate the Developer server to SQL Server 2017 but I'd prefer not to do that till the end of the year and I need to test replication immediately.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Phil.

Answer (score 0):

You can have [SQL Server 2012 Developer evaluation version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29066) (available for 180 days) and at the end of the year, you can make a decision to pay for license or upgrade to higher versions(SQL 2014 or higher), where developer edition is free.

Comment: Link here is 404